# Why I am getting Error on p->count? Value should be Inserted

Tags: c++

inheriting two classes in class c and by using the c class pointer Accessing the class a member

```
class a { int count; }; 
class b{ int* value; }; 
class c : public a, public b { }; 
int main() { 
  c* p = new c; p->count = 0; return 0;
}
```

Comment: `a` and `b` only have `private` members.

Comment: Suppose b class have public members then can i insert value in p->value?

Comment: If you want to be able to access `value` from outside of the inheritance hierarchy, you need to make it `public`.

Comment: but  value is a pointer variable

Comment: ***but value is a pointer variable*** Having a pointer to your object makes no difference to public / private / protected.

Comment: @KhalidJaved That is true but it has no bearing at all on the situation.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to use `new` in order to declare instances of objects.

Answer (score 2):

The default access level for classes is private. Change it to public:

```
class a {
 public:
   int count;
 };
```

Or change it to a struct whose default access level is public:

```
struct a {
   int count;
};
```

Do the same for class b.

Comment: Alternatively use `struct` instead of `class`

Comment: Good point! I would amend my answer to agree with your suggestion as the simplest and most appropriate fix here.